# Where to put the import module in a new installation of ng-2 Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, module, angular-ui-bootstrap, systemjs, import-module

I'm a complete newbie attempting to setup ng2 Bootstrap (Angular2 with Bootstrap4 css) using this [tutorial](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started), so far I've installed the dependencies: **Angular** (requires Angular version 2 or higher, tested with 2.0-rc.5) **Bootstrap CSS** (tested with version 4.0 alpha V3) and I've started the application:

The problem is I don't know where to add the following line of code without causing errors:

> Once installed you need to import our main module.

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

> The only remaining part is to list the imported module in your
>   application module. You should end up with the code similar to:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule, ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**UPDATE 3:** These are all the files in question I only changed the system.config.js according to the suggestion, and the app.module.ts, am I missing anything else? When I try to run it like this I get a blank page, and it doesn't load it seems that import [**NgbModule**] in app.module is the problem that causes a blank page. **How do I properly import it?**

**System.Config.JS**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@ng-bootstrap':'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },

    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
 '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap':{ main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];



  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  // No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

**AppModule.TS**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, NgbModule ],

  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Main.TS**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**App.Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 2 2 App</h1> <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div><div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div><div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div></div>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

So far I've tried replacing the code of main.ts inside the app folder, but I can't get it to work. My question is **How do I import the main module, and do I replace the existing code or just add on to it?** I'm just trying to get ng2-bootstrap to work properly, any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

This is my folder structure to help solve this problem. Thanks!

```
 vzlr-stack/
     ├──typings/
     ├──node_modules/
     ├──e2e/      
     ├──app/   
       ├──app.component.js
       ├──app.component.js.map
       ├──app.component.spec.js
       ├──app.component.spec.js.map
       ├──app.component.spec.ts
       ├──app.component.ts
       ├──app.module.js
       ├──app.module.js.map
       ├──app.module.ts
       ├──main.js
       ├──main.js.map
       ├──main.ts
     ├──wallaby.js
     ├──typings.json
     ├──tslint.json
     ├──tsconfig.json
     ├──systemjs.config.js
     ├──styles.css
     ├──Readme.md
     ├──protractor.config.js
     ├──package.json
     ├──LICENSE
     ├──karma-test-shim.js
     ├──karma.conf.js
     ├──index.html
     ├──dockerfile
     ├──CHANGELOG.md
     ├──.travis.yml
     ├──.gitignore
     ├──.editorconfig
     ├──.dockerignore
```

Comment: I can't see any request to @ng-bootstrap module in the console. Have you included the reference to the @ng-bootstrap module in `system-config.ts`?

Comment: I can't find the system-config.ts file; I only have a system.config.js file inside the app folder, is that what u mean?

Comment: yeah..`system.config.ts`(name doesn't matter,actually). so can you verify that you added the reference to @ng-bootstrap package there?

Comment: Can you explain, exactly what do I have to add to the system.config.js? I tried to paste the above code: import module into the system.config.js file, but then I get a blank grey page like this: i.is.cc/C0YIRKt.jpg Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2**
You see blank page because of 404 not found errors. When you use `import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'`, it is importing classes definition of all the ng-bootstrap components at once. So you need not to define them separately for every component(tabs,accordion,rating..) This is what `NgbModule` does. Export definition of all core components. This is causing this problem.(Maybe try to update to latest version solve this issue)
The work around this problem is individually importing the components. For example, you want to use **rating** component. Then you need to update your systemjs configuration.

You need to add configuration setting in `system.config.js` for `@ng-bootstrap` package.

You can apply user's configuration via `System.config({ map, packages })`

```
  var map = {//Map relative paths to URLs by setting
    '@ng-bootstrap':'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap'
 };

  var packages = { // packages tells the System loader how to load
    '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating':{ main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
   };
```

Your **app.module.ts** should look like this:

```
    .....
   import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
   import  { NgbRatingModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/rating';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent],
     imports:      [BrowserModule,NgbRatingModule], //root level definition of *NgbRatingModule*
     bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
   })

  export class AppModule {
   .....
  }
```

Now you can use it anywhere in the application.
Like in **app.component.ts**

```
  import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
     .......
   @Component({
       selector:'my-app',
        template:`<h1>Angular2 App </h1>  
                     <ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate"></ngb-rating>
                 `,
             directives:[],
             providers:[]
     })

    export class AppComponent{
        currentRate = 8;
        constructor(){
              ......
         }
       }
```

In the same way, you can use other like `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip` components also. Hope this solution will work for you.

Comment: Where do I put the import {NgbModule} from @ng-bootstrap? app.component.ts, main.js, etc..

Comment: Include it in `app.module.ts`. Then use it by adding in `imports` object.

Comment: I added an update to the question with the code I tried. For some reason I still get an error when I added the code. Can you check to see if I added it correctly or do I have to add it somewhere else besides the app.component.ts?

Comment: Check my latest Update with all the files: When I try to run it like this I get a blank page, and it doesn't load when I add: import [NgbModule] in app.module.ts

Comment: Are you  getting 404 not found  `...../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/collapse.js` and so on  in console? Can you confirm these errors?

Comment: @ChosenJuan I have updated the solution. It will work definitely(worked fine for me).

Comment: Here's what I got it seems to work just fine: i.is.cc/HO6PFaB.jpg  Just one question are the directives[] and providers [] supposed to do something or not?

Comment: @ChosenJuan Syntax in the image doesn't seem to be correct. You can refer to [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial. It will clear all your doubts regarding this.

Comment: I've been going though all the tutorials. I just wanted to correctly set up ngbootstrap. Thanks for your help Kunal!

Answer (score 0):

I was having my own difficulties, and this post helped greatly, as of current Kunal Sharma's post is 90% what the current process is, as I don't have 50 reputation I can't comment on that answer to request a change so this is for anyone with the same problem. (404 on @ng-bootstrap)

I didn't think about modifying the systemjs.config.js file as I am using typescript, well you do have to modify it. Here are the current file change requirements:

Changes to **app.module.ts**

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
imports: [
BrowserModule,
...
NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

Change to **systemjs.config.js:**

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
   ...
  '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
```