# Can`t install angular2 material using npm install @angular/material

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

I try install angular2 material by `npm install @angular/material` command:

```
[xxx@Latitude-E5550 quickstart]$ npm install @angular/material
    angular-quickstart@1.0.0 /home/xxx/quickstart
    └── @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.1 

    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

also I try add `import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';` to `app.module.ts` by [this](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) tutotrial.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  MaterialModule.forRoot() ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I start app I get this errors:

[image]

In node_modules folder @angular/material after installation not exist:

[image]

also I try do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262372/angular-material-2-on-quickstart-rc5) tutorial but but I get errors on server start:

`app/app.module.ts(9,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MaterialModule'`

---

***package.json***

```
 {
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

---

***angular-cli***

```
~quickstart]$ ng -v
(node:14753) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
node: 6.9.1
os: linux x64
```

Comment: Try this npm install @angular/material --save

Comment: Please do follow this link https://material.angular.io/

Comment: `npm install @angular/material --save` not helped.

Comment: Link also because `npm install @angular/material` not working, this command is from you link.

Comment: You have to install `angular-cli` first.`npm install -g angular-cli`. I guess you don't have it because `angular-cli` uses webpack instead of SystemJS. The same thing with ports, cli uses `4200` and in your case your system connects to `3000`.

Comment: What is your angular2 version? Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Here is a crazy question: are you in the right directory when running `npm install @angular/material`?

Comment: echonax - I use Angular 2.4.0 see package.json on updated post .

Comment: K. Daniek I have installed angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10 see post.

Comment: @EdgarasKarka if you have material inside your package.json, did you try running npm install where the package.json is? Still not getting material inside the folder?

Comment: have you installed hammarjs before using angular2 material?

Comment: @EdgarasKarka You have installed cli, right? And what happens when you are  trying to compile the code? If there are any errors, post them.

Comment: @echonax yes it is my problem

Comment: @micronyks yes I have hammarjs in  package.json

Comment: @K.Daniek I use `npm install` and `npm start' for start app

Comment: You have to use `ng serve` to start the app when you are using `angular-cli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

check out this link https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started